# Why this assignment using `which` does not work in `data.table`?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with this structure:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1336 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2013-02-01 00:03:49" "2013-02-01 00:03:49" "2013-02-01 00:07:54" ...
 $ hour     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ price    : num  21 22 21 22 21 22 35 35.5 35.9 38 ...
 $ qty      : num  50 20 50 20 50 20 15 20 3 30 ...
 $ timegroup: int  1 250 506 757 758 1004 1253 1 250 506 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Example data are:

```
> df
                timestamp hour price qty timegroup
   1: 2013-02-01 00:03:49    1    21  50         1
   2: 2013-02-01 00:03:49    1    22  20         1
   3: 2013-02-01 00:07:54    1    21  50         1
   4: 2013-02-01 00:07:54    1    22  20         1
   5: 2013-02-01 00:11:59    1    21  50         1
  ---                                             
1332: 2013-04-07 00:12:10    1    40  50         1
1333: 2013-04-07 00:12:10    1    47  50         1
1334: 2013-04-07 00:12:10    1    53  15         1
1335: 2013-04-07 00:12:10    1    78  50         1
1336: 2013-04-07 00:12:10    1   345  25         1
```

And I am trying to clean the data, because there are duplicit entries at different times. For example rows 3 and 4 should be deleted because they are duplicit with row 1 and 2, only registered at different time. I am trying to achieve this by generating groups of timestamps and then comparing the subsequent groups among themselves. But I got stuck at generating the groups of date-times.

```
groups <- unique(df$timestamp)
df[,timegroup:=which(timestamp==groups)]
```

but for some unknown reason the `timegroup` column does not want to create itself. Reason is this error, which I does not help me much

```
Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(timestamp, groups) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(timegroup, which(timestamp == groups))) :
  Supplied 7 items to be assigned to 1336 items of column 'timegroup' (recycled leaving remainder of 6 items).
```

Also `sapply` and `for` loop do work.

Can anyone tell me why? It seems to be somehow connected with the format... Thank you.

Comment: try `df[,timegroup:=which(timestamp==groups), by=timestamp]`. The problem is that `timestamp` and `groups` are both vectors of unequal length.

Comment: how, prosaic, thanks a lot, solved my problem.

Comment: Why are the 3rd and the 4th rows duplicate of 1 and 2 exactly? The timestamps aren't completely identical...

Comment: @Arun row 1=3 and 2=4 except for timestamp, otherwise said the subsets [1:2,2:4]==[3:4,2:4] is true. Imagine having a bot that checks periodically and registers what it sees and I need to clean the data to only contain changes.

Comment: +1 @eddi, exactly what I was thinking. From what you say, why not just `dt[!duplicated(dt[, c(-1), with=FALSE])]`

Comment: @Arun At time t, the bot registers two entries, as above, at time t+1 it registers again the same two entries, at time t+2 he might register these two entries plus one that entered queue. Hence, state at t is equal to state at t+1, but not t=t+2 or t+1=t+2.

Comment: @tomaskrehlik, sorry I don't follow your last statement. Am I the only one not understanding the problem yet? :)

Comment: @tomaskrehlik, After your edit in comment, I think I follow your problem. Check out my answer if you're interested. It'd be great if you could tell me how Ricardo's answer answers your question. I don't think it does.

Comment: @tomaskrehlik, as Arun pointed out, I dont think my answer actually resolves the issue.  I tried to remove it, but since it was marked as accepted, I cannot.  Please feel free to mark it as unaccepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your immediate problem is this:

```
df[, timegroup := .GRP, by = timestamp]
```

I don't think I understand too well the general problem you're facing to suggest a solution for that.

My relatively wild guess is that you want this:

```
df = data.table(timestamp = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), var1 = c(1,2,1,2,1,3), var2 = c(1,2,1,2,1,4))
groups = unique(df$timestamp)
groups.duplicated = c(FALSE, sapply(seq_along(groups)[-1], function(i) {
    identical(df[timestamp == groups[i-1], -1],
              df[timestamp == groups[i], -1])
}))

df[timestamp %in% groups[!groups.duplicated]]
#   timestamp var1 var2
#1:         1    1    1
#2:         1    2    2
#3:         3    1    1
#4:         3    3    4
```

Comment: @Arun: the `sapply` loops over unique timestamps, so `i` is the index of the timestamp (the `.GRP` above if you wish)

Comment: I get this error. `Error in i - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` when I copy/paste your code.

Comment: Eddi, check my data and the explanation for what the output should be to get an idea. That is, if I correctly understood OP's last comment.

Comment: @Arun - fixed the indexing, thanks to your data - note the differences between these two answers - you're only counting the number of observations, while I'm doing the full diff

Comment: ,I've two id columns: `grp` and `N`. `N` as you mention just counts the observations by `time`. But `grp` is the trickiest. Together, they allow for removal of right entries, I believe. Can I try my data with your code?

Comment: @Arun - yes you can try your data (as long as you rename time->timestamp) - the other difference of this one is that I assumed that "duplicate" observations can only come one after another

Comment: I changed `time` to `timestamp` and replaced the `.[0-9]` with nothing so that timestamp resembles `rep(1:3, c(7,6,1))` and no rows were removed... What am I doing wrong? I also tried by *just* replacing time by timestamp and not changing the values... and get the same data as input back.

Comment: @Arun - you should see `timestamp==1.2` removed and that's it - I just took your `DT`, and did `df = copy(DT); setnames(df, "time", "timestamp")` and ran above code

Comment: Yes now I see what you mention. I guess we both understand it different. It's still not clear to me. I guess we leave the OP decide :).

Comment: Sorry for replying late, moving to a different place and no internet here. :-/ Nevertheless, this resolves my issue! (And I learned a new command, never heard of seq_along before, thanks a lot!) I have already sketched some working version of the code working with which, which is not nice, but works. Anyway, this is the answer I wanted.